# Counting first occurence Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I've got a table with a structure something like the following:

```
Vendor    Product    Release Year

A         A          2008 
A         B          2009
B         D          2008
D         F          2010
```

What I'm looking to do is count the number of new vendors we've had each release something each year. So for instance, i8n the above example 2008 would contain two vendors, 2009 zero and 2010 one.

Thinking like a programmer I'd probably maintain a list with earliest release date for each product and then update the list with a simple if clause.

My data needs to stay in Google Sheets in the form of a pivot table. 
How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

## Short answer

Use [QUERY](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en)

## Formula

```
=query(
   query(A:C,"select A,MIN(C) where C>0 group by A label MIN(C) 'Year Release'",1),
   "select Col2, Count(Col1) group by Col2 label Count(Col1) 'New Vendors'",1
)
```

### Result

```
Year Release    New Vendors
        2008              2
        2010              1
```